# Is it possible to work with an MS-Access application via Remote Desktop Services?

Tags: ms-access, remote-desktop

Background: Many years ago I developed a MS-Access database application for a small company with about 10 users. They used to work in an office with a Windows Server and LAN.
The database is backend-fronted. One Access file with the data on the Windows file server and an Access frontend on each User PC. I still add new forms and funtions to that database application.

Now everybody is working from home. Not everybody is using the database all the time. So I setup 3 PCs in that office with the database application installed. Now users connect through the FortiGate firewall per Remote Desktop Connection (part of Windows) to the PCs in the office and they use the database on those PCs. That works fine.

Now the boss of the company thinks about downsizing the office. For this reason it would be good if I have only the server in the office. Or maybe no server at all, everything in the cloud.

I read about Remote Desktop Services on Windows Server. And I guess in theory this is what I need instead of the PCs in the office, correct?
I guess with Remote Desktop Services the performance of the database should be similar to what the users see now, with the separate PCs, correct?
Is there any downside using Remote Desktop Services?

And, as an additional question: Is it possible to "rent a server" with Remote Desktop Services from MS or another reputable company so that I don't need my own server? If it exist: What is it called?

Currently I use: MS-Server 2012R2 Essential, Window 10 PCs, MS-Access 2016, we also use Office 365 but currently only the email accounts

Answer (score 1):

> I read about Remote Desktop Services on Windows Server. And I guess in
>   theory this is what I need instead of the PCs in the office, correct?

In practice: Yes.

> I guess with Remote Desktop Services the performance of the database
>   should be similar to what the users see now, with the separate PCs,
>   correct?

Yes.

> Is there any downside using Remote Desktop Services?

Not compared to your current setup with three separate machines.
However, install of Office 365 takes special attention:

[Overview of the Office Deployment Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/overview-office-deployment-tool)